# ListIndex out of range for NEAT Algorithm

Tags: python, pygame, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Im trying to create an AI that plays a game. The game requires the AI to dodge incoming asteroids. Im using the NEAT library but for some reason I keep getting a List index error and I can't seem to figure out why. Sidenote: I am new to NEAT and genetic algorithms.

I want my game to run with a single genome at a time.

```
def main(genomes, config):
    ge = []        # List to hold all genome objects
    nets = []      # List to hold the NN associated with each genome
    players = []   # List to hold the player objects (Contains x y coordinates and other attributes)

   # To the three lists append each of the following objects: NNs, genomes and players 
     - such that they each match with their index position.
     Example: players[1] has its genome stored at genome[1] and it's neural network at nets[1]

    for __, g in genomes:
        net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(g, config)
        nets.append(net)
        players.append(player())
        g.fitness = 0
        ge.append(g)


    # Asteroid objects that are meant to be avoided
      asteroid(img_num, max_y, speed, width, height, threshold_score)
    asteroids = [0,
             asteroid(1, playable_height-39, 10.5, 35, 39, 0),
             asteroid(2, playable_height-25, 15, 25, 25, 10),
             asteroid(3, playable_height-30, 12.5, 30, 30, 15),
             asteroid(4, playable_height-35, 10, 35, 35, 20)]




    for x in range(len(players)):  # Suspected source of error
        game_over = False
        while not game_over:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()


            # Calculates the output of the current player playing using it's neural network

            output = nets[x].activate(((players[x].y / 169),
                GetDistance(1, players[x], asteroids),
                GetDistance(2, players[x], asteroids),
                GetDistance(3, players[x], asteroids),
                GetDistance(4, players[x], asteroids)))


            if output[0] > 0:
                players[x].moveDOWN()
            elif output[0] < 0:
                players[x].moveUP()



            if players[x].y > playable_height - players[x].height:
                players[x].y = playable_height - players[x].height
            elif players[x].y < 0:
                players[x].y = 0
            window.fill((0, 0, 0))
            window.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
            players[x].draw()


           # Checks to see if asteroid has been dodged and then increases fitness by 5 for that genome. If collision occurs remove the genome, NN and player from their lists.

            for n in range(1, 5):
                if asteroids[n].x < 0:
                    players[x].score += 1
                    ge[x].fitness += 5
                asteroids[n].move(players[x])
                if asteroids[n].collision(players[x]):
                    asteroids[n].reset(asteroids)
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    del players[x]
                    del nets[x]
                    del ge[x]
                    game_over = True


            Text_display("Score: " + str(players[x].score * 100), white, 0, 200)
            Text_display("Asteroid 1: " + str(GetDistance(1, players[x], asteroids)), white, 0, 220)
            Text_display("Asteroid 2: " + str(GetDistance(2, players[x], asteroids)), white, 0, 240)
            Text_display("Asteroid 3: " + str(GetDistance(3, players[x], asteroids)), white, 0, 260)
            Text_display("Asteroid 4: " + str(GetDistance(4, players[x], asteroids)), white, 0, 280)
            Text_display("Space Ship Position: " + str(players[x].y / 169), white, 0, 300)





            pygame.display.update()





# Set up function for the NEAT library

def run(config_path):
    config = neat.config.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation, config_path)
    p = neat.Population(config)

    p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
    stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
    p.add_reporter(stats)

    winner = p.run(main, 100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, "NEATconfig.txt")
    run(config_path)
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message and the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @Rabbid76 It occurs in the line output = nets[x].activate and the error is list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you write a for loop of player before while loop so that index error happen. I suggest you should try this

```py
game_over = False
while not game_over:
    for x,_ in enumerate(players):
        output = nets[x].activate(((players[x].y / 169),
            GetDistance(1, players[x], asteroids),
            GetDistance(2, players[x], asteroids),
            GetDistance(3, players[x], asteroids),
            GetDistance(4, players[x], asteroids)))
            # and just put all your code after this I think it gonna be work :)
```